# timeCycle activity won't work

Tags: activiti

I'm using activiti 5.11
i specify repeating interval like this (I try both expressions) :

```
<intermediateCatchEvent id="timerintermediatecatchevent1" name="TimerCatchEvent">
  <timerEventDefinition>
      <timeCycle>0 0/1 * * * ?</timeCycle>
  </timerEventDefinition></intermediateCatchEvent>


<timerEventDefinition>
<timeCycle>R3/PT1M</timeCycle></timerEventDefinition>
```

but the timer is called only one time without executing any repetition even if i specify a time interval for repetition, i'm using intermediateThrowEvent after the timer branch
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second expression I'm not sure if it should work, the first it should (every minute).

But what you are showing looks a bit weird for a process. You have an intermetiate event, which 'fires' every minute.

I suspect that what is happening is the following: The timer does not have any duration (it's not waiting there for any time). After it arrives to the timer, as it does not have duration the process instance continues, and finishes. As the process instance is finished, the timer does not run. If you want the process to stop at the timer, probably you should set a duration as well.